# Get value of default drop down menu value in pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm writing tests for a client's website and need to write a test case that makes sure that a certain option is always the default selection in a dropdown menu.

Here's the HTML code

```html
<select id="id" name="server" onchange="function();">
    <option value="optionA">Option A</option>
    <option selected="" value="optionB">Option B</option>
```

I need to test that Option B is always the default one.
I don't know how to get the value of the option that's selected by default.
I'm using pytest.

Answer (score 0):

The key element that you want to assert when opening the page is:

`'select option[selected][value="optionB"]'`

Here's the full `pytest`-runnable solution:

```py
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from unittest import TestCase


class MyTestClass(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = None
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        if "linux" in sys.platform:
            options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_experimental_option(
            "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"],
        )
        prefs = {
            "credentials_enable_service": False,
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.driver:
            try:
                if self.driver.service.process:
                    self.driver.quit()
            except Exception:
                pass

    def open(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

    def wait_for_element_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was not visible after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def assert_element(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)


    def test_selection(self):
        url = (
            'data:text/html,'
            '<select id="id" name="server" onchange="function();">'
            '<option value="optionA">Option A</option>'
            '<option selected="" value="optionB">Option B</option>'
        )
        self.open(url)
        self.assert_element('select option[selected][value="optionB"]')
        time.sleep(1)  # Not needed, but it runs too fast for eyes.
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) pytest framework and reduce the code to a few lines. `pip install seleniumbase` and then run the code below with `pytest`. If the test runs too fast for you to see, add `--demo` as a SeleniumBase pytest command-line option. It also prints the text of the default option and asserts that text as well:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class SelectionTests(BaseCase):

    def test_selection(self):
        url = (
            'data:text/html,'
            '<select id="id" name="server" onchange="function();">'
            '<option value="optionA">Option A</option>'
            '<option selected="" value="optionB">Option B</option>'
        )
        self.open(url)

        selected_option = self.get_text("select option[selected]")
        print(selected_option)
        self.assertEqual(selected_option, "Option B")

        self.assert_element('select option[selected][value="optionB"]')
```